# Setting a range using two cells from different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, range, worksheet

I'm trying to go through a calendar to set a moving 13 day range for each column. If the 13 day range goes over the current month, I want to be able to go to the next sheet, and find me the where that ends. I am not however, able to reference both sheets at the same time. `Set rng13 = .Range(start13, finish13)`

I plan on running a boolean check in that 13 day range to see if all 13 days are True.

Any help or recommendation would be appreciated

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
    Set onePersonLoop = .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Offset(-1).End(xlToRight).Offset(, -2)
    Set onePersonLoop = .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Offset(-1).End(xlToRight).Offset(, -2)

    For rowNum = 6 To 24 Step 6
        Set nameLocation = .Cells(rowNum, colNum).Offset(-2, -1).EntireRow.Cells(1, 2)
        For colNum = 4 To onePersonLoop.
            Set start13 = .Cells(rowNum, colNum)
            If start13.Column <= onePersonLoop.Column - 12 Then
                Set finish13 = .Cells(rowNum, colNum + 12)
            ElseIf start13.Column > onePersonLoop.Column - 12 Then
                carryOver = start13.Column - (onePersonLoop.Column - 12)
                Worksheets(i + 1).Activate
                Set finish13 = Worksheets(i + 1).Cells(rowNum, 3 + carryOver)
                Set rng13 = .Range(start13, finish13)
            End If
        Next colNum
    Next rowNum
End With
```

Comment: What if you had two ranges? rng13a could be the part of the range on the first sheet, and rng13b can be the part of the range that was a carryover. Then do the Boolean check on both ranges.